# Ошибка при запуске кода через терминал, vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После установки minGW услышал, что нужно в настройках переключить запуск кода через терминал. Выходит эта ошибка, что делать?

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: *"услышал, что нужно в настройках переключить запуск кода через терминал"* Не понял. Покажите, где услышали, и что точно там написано. Ваша ошибка - потому что не добавили `g++` в PATH, или не перезапустили VSC после этого, при чем тут терминал - не понимаю.